# armar stored procedure con bifurcaciones en sql server 2000

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

estoy complicado a la hora de armar un stored procedure.
La query está hardcodeada en php de esta forma:

```
if(trim($id) != ''){ 
      $query = "select * from PACIENTES where idpac in (select pac_id from contacto where id = ".$id.") ";

   }else{ 
        $query = "select * from PACIENTES where 1=1 ";
      if(trim($historia_clinica) != ''){
        $query = $query." and historia_clinica_nro = '".$historia_clinica."'";
      }
      if(trim($documento) != ''){
        $query = $query." and numero = '".$documento."'";  
      }
      if(trim($nombre) != ''){
        $query = $query." and nombre like '%".str_replace(' ', '%',$nombre)."%'";  
      }
      if(trim($telefono) != ''){
        $query = $query." and (ntelefo1 = '".$telefono."' or ntelefo2 = '".$telefono."' ) ";
      }
      if(trim($email) != ''){
        //$query =$query." and mail = '".$email."'";
        $query = $query." and hc_nro  in (select idHistoriaClinica from paciente where mail ='".$email."')";
      }
      if(trim($id_paciente) != ''){
        $query =$query." and id_paciente = '".$id_paciente."'";
      }
    }
```

Estuve escribiendo algo así:

```
create sp_getPacientes
@id varchar(3),
@historia_clinica varchar(10),
@documento varchar(10),
@nombre varchar(20),
@telefono varchar(15),
@email varchar(30),
@id_paciente varchar(5)
as
 begin
   if @id is not null 
     select * from PACIENTES where id_paciente in (select paciente_id from 
    contacto where id = @id);
```

Necesito la lógica y un ejemplo, no pido que me resuelvan todo.
Muchas gracias! Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo si recibe el parámetro `@id` devuelve *todos* los campos del/los registro/s de la tabla PACIENTES que cuyo `idpac` se encuentre en la tabla `CONTACTOS`. Esto es lo que ya codificaste en tu SP.

En caso que dicho parámetro sea el `string` nulo (`''`), en el ELSE, arma un `SELECT` que de manera predeterminada trae todos los Pacientes, por eso el `where 1 = 1`, esta condición siempre es verdadera.

A esta condición inicial, le adiciona las condiciones indicadas por el resto de los parámetros que no sean string nulo.

Por ejemplo si recibe '@id = '', @documento='1234',...`el`select` resultante sería:

```
SELECT * FROM PACIENTES
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND documento = '1234'
```

o sea sólo los pacientes con documento igual a '1234'. De manera similar con cada uno de los demás parámetros

Esto último de utilizar parámetros opcionales lo puedes lograr sin necesidad de preguntar si el parámetro es `''` utilizando `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Pacientes
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND (historia_clinica_nro = @historia_clinica OR @historia_clinica = '')
    AND (documento = @documento OR @documento = '')
    AND (<campo_tabla> = @parametro OR @parametro = '')
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Comment: voy a probarlo! 
Muchas gracias!